# How to change a character of an string into a different character?

Tags: javascript, arrays, character, converters

I want to convert the space in a string into another character.

Ex:
 `var country = "United States"`

I want the space to be "-" so: 
`var country = "Unites-States"`

This is what I tried:

```
var country ="United States";
var countryArray = country.split(" ");
var newCountry = function(){
for(i=0;i<countryArray.length;i++){
    if(countryArray[i]===","){
    return countryArray[i]="-";}
}
```

Comment: and what about simple RegEx : `country = country.replace(" ","-")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function :

```
var country = "United States";
//var newCountry = country.replace(' ', '-'); //first space only
var newCountry = country.replace(/\s+/g, '-'); //this uses regexp if there is more than just 1 space / tab character.
```

Comment: that only replace the first space, for example > United States of America will be United-States of America

Comment: Wow I was in the middle of answering when you answered it. :-)

Comment: Check the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
country.replace(/ /g, ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the string replace method?

Example:

```
newCountry = country.replace(" ", "-");
```